# using xml param inside a function

Tags: xpath, xslt

Having declared

```
<xsl:param name='suffix'>some_string</xsl:param>
```

I tried to use its value in a function call like this

```
<xsl:when test='fn:ends-with(@name, {$suffix})'>
```

which ended with the following error:

> XPST0003: XPath syntax error at char
>   20 on line 34 in {fn:ends-with(@name,
>   {$}:
>       Unexpected token "{" in path expression

What's the proper way to use parameter's value in a function call in XSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:when test='fn:ends-with(@name, $suffix)'>
```